# How to split field 1 into distinct rows but keep field 2 copied for each new row created

Tags: text-processing, awk, columns

Input:

Note: 2 columns separated by a tab, regular spaces separating words in column 2.

```
1   the mouse is dead
2   hit the wall
3   winter lasts forever
```

Wanted output:

```
1   the
1   mouse
1   is
1   dead
2   hit
2   the
2   wall
3   winter
3   lasts
3   forever
```

Is `awk` the way to go for this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Well, the first field is `$1`, `NF` holds the number of fields on the line, we can access the fields with `$i` where `i` is a variable, and loops work almost like in C. So:

```
$ awk '{for (i = 2; i <= NF; i++) printf "%s\t%s\n", $1, $i} ' < blah
1       the
1       mouse
...
```

(This doesn't differentiate between space and tab as field separator.)

Answer (score 5):

With GNU `sed`:

```
sed -E 's/^((\S+\s+)\S+)\s+/&\n\2/;P;D'
```

It's just uglier with POSIX `sed` syntax:

```
s='[[:space:]]\{1,\}' S='[^[:space:]]\{1,\}'
sed "s/^\(\($S$s\)$S\)$s/&\\
\2/;P;D"
```

Answer (score 2):

another awk one:

```
~$>echo '1   the mouse is dead
2   hit the wall
3   winter lasts forever
' | awk 'BEGIN { RS="[[:space:]]+"; } /^[[:digit:]]+$/ {line=$1; next}; { print line "\t" $1; }'
1   the
1   mouse
1   is
1   dead
2   hit
2   the
2   wall
3   winter
3   lasts
3   forever
```

and laid out slightly better..

```
# split all parts into single word records.
BEGIN { RS="[[:space:]]+"; } 

# if the record is a number the save
/^[[:digit:]]+$/ { line=$1; next }; 
# else use last saved line number and this record to format output.
{ print line "\t" $1; }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use the split function with awk:

```
awk -F"\t" 'BEGIN { OFS="\t" } { cols=split($2,arr," "); for ( i=1; i<=cols; i++ ) { print $1,arr[i] }}'
```